# how to change the color of the graph depending on the value of the column in R

Tags: r, plot

I have two vectors, where vector x have distribution and vector y have 1 and 0 values.

```
x = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0.5, 2)
y = seq.int(from = 0, to = 1, length.out = 50)
data <- data.frame(x,y)
```

I need to build a line graph of data X, where the color of the graph will depend on the corresponding value of Y. For example: the graph will be black when Y is 0 and red when Y is 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work? I assumed that `y` is a sequence of `0`s and `1`s instead of a sequence of numbers between `0` and `1`.

```
x = rnorm(n = 50, mean = 0.5, 2)
y = sample(c(0,1), replace=TRUE, size=50)
data <- data.frame(x,y)
colors <- c("black", "red")
plot(data$x, col="white")
for (i in 1:49) {
  lines(c(i, i+1), c(data$x[i], data$x[i+1]), col=colors[data$y[i]+1])
}
```